# WebDAV : Is it possible to only retrieve folders using PropFind?

Tags: file, recursion, directory, webdav, propfind

In WebDAV, is it possible to only retrieve folders using PropFind ?

The reason I ask is that looping recursive to all the folders and files on the server takes a lot of time because some folders contain a lot of files.

Is there a way to only retrieve the folder names ?

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no such thing in base WebDAV.

If the server supports WebDAV SEARCH (RFC 5323), the answer is different (but ot's not widely implemented).